# When l use filter not get any output

Tags: maven, jersey, jax-rs, resteasy, web.xml

When l use filter not got any output, but I remove filter when I got output. this is the my **web.xml** ,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>MYApp</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-hibernate-resteasy.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/resteasy</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/pages</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
           <param-value>/(css|js|img|resources|(WEB-INF/pages))/.*</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>jersey</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resteasy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

There are filter use for add for **Viewable** Jax-rs web service. Why can't get any output ?

How I solve  it?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the filter as `SpringServlet` but already have a `<servlet>` configured.  I think those are incompatible, I think you can make a filter of your own by using a class that implements one of: `ContainerRequestFilter`, `ContainerResponseFilter`, `ClientRequestFilter`, `ClientResponsFilter` (or `WriterInterceptor` / `ReaderInterceptor`) in your `<filter>` tag.  Or just remove your `<servlet>` configuration and see what that does.

See some Jersey documentation about Filters and Interceptors here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html

Hopefully that gets you moving in the right direction.